# How to make self.dynamicType into a typealias

Tags: swift, abstraction, swift-protocols

Basically I want to add a typealias to `UIViewController` or any other default swift classes. The reasoning behind this is that I want to abstract my code so that I can access some static functions by just using `this` instead of `self.dynamicType`

```
extension UIViewController {
    typealias this = TheClassThatSubclassedThis
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    func doStuff() {
        this.doStaticStuff()
    }

    static func doStaticStuff() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know this is possible by creating a `protocol`, then just implement said protocol to the class I want to implement it to, like this

```
protocol CanAccessStaticSelf {
    typealias this
}

class DetailVC: UIViewController, CanAccessStaticSelf {
    typealias this = DetailVC
}
```

But is there a more efficient way to do this? Like for example, by just subclassing a certain class or by extending a superclass?

Like this for example

```
extension UIViewController {
    public static var defaultNibName: String {
        return self.description().componentsSeparatedByString(".").dropFirst().joinWithSeparator(".")
    }
}

class DetailVC: UIViewController, CanAccessStaticSelf {
    func doSomeStuffAgain() {
        // no other code just subclass and I can access self.dynamicType as just `this`
        print(this.defaultNibName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
protocol CanAccessStaticSelf {
    typealias this = Self
}
```

...but what you are trying to achieve looks somewhat confusing to me ;-(

---

Thanks to [this proposal from Erica Sadun](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) we all might be able to use the `Self` keyword for that in the near future.

For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    static func staticMethod() { ... }
    func instanceMethod() {
        MyClass.staticMethod()
        Self.staticMethod()
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, that's exactly what I am looking for I didn't know of that `Self` property until now

Comment: @ZonilyJame Nice! Not technically a property; more of a type identifier of sorts.

Comment: yeah apparently it's a protocol thingy that is used to return what thing is using them

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to access through this.
but you can access through "UIViewController.defaultNibName".

Comment: it is actually possible to access `defaultNibName` using `this` but I'd need to do this code snippet first `typealias this = SomeClassNameHere`